# Console Application C# - fresh page

Tags: c#, console-application, do-while

I am basically writing a program with a welcome screen. And at the bottom it says on it 'press a key to continue: '. However, what I want to do is let the user input any key and then for the console to wipe the above 'Welcome Screen' and continue with the program.

I have tried a do while loop but I only want the welcome screen to be looped once then stop. All it seems to be doing is continuously printing the welcome screen until i press something.

Any help would be great.

Thanks.

This is what my code looks like so far...

```
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Continue");
do 
{
    while (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape) 
    {
    // Full program
    }       
} while (! Console.KeyAvailable);
```

Answer (score 5):

To clear the console, you can use [`Clear`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.clear%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Given your requirements, it sounds like you don't need loops at all:

```
Console.WriteLine("");
Console.WriteLine("Press any key to Continue");
if (Console.ReadKey(true).Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
{
     Console.Clear(); // Clears the message as per your requirements

     // Full program here
}
```